# Invalid field number in Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

While loading crystal report using C# i got a error like "Load report failed" and inner error as "Invalid field number". Error occurs in the following line of code

```
 oReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(objHashTable["RequestFile"])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Load report failed workaround is following

1. right click on report and select verify Database to update your
   report and replace previous report with this one
2. when your report file name spell not match or file not exist.

Comment: It was a **field name** mismatch between dataset and query. Anyway thanks for reply.